# Sort python list with comparing integers

Tags: python, sorting, heroku, flask, jinja2

Here are my original two (2) functions:

```
def user_bible(query):
    output = requests.get("http://getbible.net/json?passage={0}".format(query))
    json_dict_output = json.loads(output.text.strip("();"))

    before_for_loop_parse = json_dict_output[u'book'][0][u'chapter'] #[u'2'][u'verse']

    keys = before_for_loop_parse.keys()
    keys.sort(compare_number_strings)

    stored_list = []

    for k in keys:
        stored_list.append(before_for_loop_parse[k][u'verse'])



    return parse_rough_draft(json_dict_output)
```

and my second small function:

`def compare_number_strings(string1, string2):
    return cmp(int(string1), int(string2))`

Then my tutor helped me edit a new function which allowed for chapter and verse numbers to be presented in the function's output

```
def parse_rough_draft(json_dict_output):
    books = json_dict_output[u'book']
    result_dict={}
    for i in books:
        book_name_variable = i[u'book_name']
        current_book_value = result_dict.setdefault(book_name_variable, {})
        chapter_variable = i[u'chapter_nr']
        chapter_value = current_book_value.setdefault(chapter_variable, {})
        all_chapter_verses_variable = i[u'chapter']
        for m in all_chapter_verses_variable.keys():
            verse = all_chapter_verses_variable[m]
            chapter_value[m] = verse[u'verse']
    return result_dict
```

But, my new function `parse rough draft():` outputs an unsorted list. I am trying to sort this list and then compare the integers of the list so the output will present verses from say "Jn 2:4-19" in proper numerical order. In this function `parse rough draft():` am I defining a dictionary above the for loop, and thus is everything in the for loop incorporated in my `result_dict` dictionary?
I added:

`keys = result_dict.keys()
    keys.sort(compare_number_strings)
    return keys`

But now the output on my jinja2 template page only prints the output ' Book: John '
from the following Bible.html template

```
</form>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% with books = messages[0] %}
        {% if books %}
        <div class="well">
            <div class="row" style="margin: 50px;margin-right: 100px; font-size:150%;">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <!--<h5>Scripture:</h5> -->
                    {% for book in books %}
                      <div class="book">
                      Book: {{book}}
                    {% for chapter in books[book]%}
                      <div class="chapter">
                      Chapter: {{chapter}}
                    {% with sorted_keys = books[book][chapter].keys() %}


                    {% for verse in sorted_keys %}
                        <div class="verse">
                        Verse: {{verse}}
                        <div class="verse-text">{{books[book][chapter][verse]}}</div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endwith %}
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
    </div>
```

The function can be seen live here:
http://shielded-brushlands-1568.herokuapp.com/Bible/

and the github repo here:
https://github.com/phillipsk/webapp/blob/master/templates/bible.html

Comment: I haven't finished reading your question yet, but one thing that jumps out at me is that rather than using a comparator, you should just pass `key=int` to the sort call. That will call `int` on the list elements to produce keys to sort the list by.

Comment: You haven't actually described what any of this code is *supposed* to do.

Comment: This could be a data modelling problem.  All of the containers appear to start out as empty python dictionaries `{}`.  Python dictionaries are unsortable key->value maps.  When you say "`parse rough draft()` outputs an unsorted list" that's not quite true.  It outputs a dictionary, and all dictionaries are always unsorted and unsortable.  There is a Python data type called a list, and one called an array, and both of these have a beginning and end (so are iterable), and can also be sorted.  Suggest initializing `chapter_value` to an empty array `[]`.  Set the 0th element blank, others->verses

Comment: Very hard to understand what is goal vs problem, info might be there but all mixed up. I suggest you edit your post to clarify, in that order, 1) what is desired output (probably from `user_bible`, give example), 2) what is input ( what `before_for_loop_parse` contains) 3) what is template that uses the output, and 4) what you tried. I think you mostly need to restructure and make certain things more obvious, then we can help.